# Set mobile mode based on screen resolution size in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile, responsive-design, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to categorize requests as mobile or desktop based on screen size instead of user agent?

For example, the iPad retina would have no problem viewing my site as a desktop, but I would want iPad 1 to be recognized as a mobile device. It would be out of control if I tried determining the screen size from the user agent for Android devices. Is there a way to do something like this in MVC:

`if (screen size < 840px)
  HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile)`

Comment: Why not add media queries to you CSS.  That is partially what they are meant for.

Comment: The mobile site is a whole new site within the MVC app (jQuery Mobile app). Some of the architecture is shared but many times the mobile uses totally different controllers, queries, .mobile views, conditional @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice), and other deep differences and handling.

Comment: You can use **DisplayModeProvider** class in MVC4. Here is the [code project link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704007/Desktop-and-Mobile-Browser-View-in-MVC-MVC-Dis) that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `HttpBrowserCapablilties` object contains a `ScreenPixelsWidth` and `ScreenPixelsHeight` property.  I suppose you could base it on that.

[HttpBrowerCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

[ScreenPixelsWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.screenpixelswidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[ScreenPixelsHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.screenpixelsheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It's only a data structure and tried getting it out of Request.Browser and screen width/height is always the same.